# AutoHotKey two different hotkey Lbutton and Lbutton down

Tags: autohotkey

I trying to create two hotkey

One for Lbutton:: "Left mouse button (single click)"
another for Left mouse button (only if holding, maybe if more than 0.2 seconds)

Or there is key list like Lbutton Down:: and Lbutton Up::?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [keyWait](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm) like this

```
LButton::
{   ;wait for the mouse button to be let go, set 0.2 second timeout
    KeyWait, LButton, T0.2
if(ErrorLevel)
{   MsgBox holding down
} else
{   MsgBox clicked
}
return
}
```